# Neither user 10085 nor current process has android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE

Tags: android

I have updated target sdk version 27 and i have given permission in `manifest` of `READ_PHONE_STATE.` Still my app is crashing on `utils.java`

```
 deviceId = TelephonyMgr.getDeviceId();
```

on this line and i also ask for run time permission for this still the issue is same

```
private void RequestMultiplePermission() {

        // Creating String Array with Permissions.
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(LoginActivity.this, new String[]
                {
                        CALL_PHONE,
                        READ_PHONE_STATE
                }, RequestPermissionCode);

    }
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {

            case RequestPermissionCode:

                if (grantResults.length > 0) {

                    boolean GetCallPermission = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    boolean GetReadphoneper = grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

                    if (GetCallPermission && GetReadphoneper) {

                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else {
                        ///Toast.makeText(Login.this,"Permission Granted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

here in this line it will crash
 deviceId = TelephonyMgr.getDeviceId();

```
public static String getUniqueDeviceId(Context context) {
        String deviceId;
        // 1 compute IMEI
        final TelephonyManager TelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        }
        deviceId = TelephonyMgr.getDeviceId(); // Requires // READ_PHONE_STATE
        if (deviceId == null) {
            // 2 android ID - unreliable
            deviceId = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
        }
        if (deviceId == null) {
            Random r = new Random();
            deviceId = String.valueOf((r.nextInt() + r.nextInt()));
        }

        e(deviceId);
        return deviceId;
    }
```

Comment: `permission in manifest` is not enough. You need runtime permissions as well

Comment: i have given run ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(LoginActivity.this, new String[]
            {
                    CALL_PHONE,
                    READ_PHONE_STATE
            }, RequestPermissionCode);
 time permission too. @VladyslavMatviienko

Comment: Ok, and when you try to do that `deviceId = TelephonyMgr.getDeviceId()`

Comment: In my Utils.java file @VladyslavMatviienko

Comment: nobody knows what is your `Utils.java`. You can call that only after you get the permissions. That's why I ask when you call it

Comment: here in this line it will crash deviceId = TelephonyMgr.getDeviceId();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using this::

```
 deviceId = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(),
                InstanceID.getInstance(context).getId());
```

Comment: What is InstanceID here?

Comment: Not in package class. Couldn’t be found

Comment: Have you implemented following in your gradle ???--
"com.google.android.gms:play-services"

Comment: My app maps. Sure, I must have

Comment: @olajide InstanceID is part of Firebase: https://firebase.google.com/support/privacy/manage-iids